# Implementation of IComparable and IComparer

Tags: c#, sorting, interface

I have been studying sorting so far, I have a
question.

Is it possible to implement both interfaces IComparable and IComparer
and make use of them in single class and use them for different
sorting purposes.

If yes, how can I do this? If not why? The thing I noticed is that
if I implement both of them, then I do not know how to use Sort
function inside of the class, because it is using only one interface.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "because it is using only one interface". If you pass a specific comparer, it will use that - otherwise it will use the `IComparable` implementation. It's pretty odd to implement both in the same class though. Why do you *want* to do that?

Comment: For example I implement both of those interfaces and then i write two different methods for sorting with required signature of those interfaces. But then inside of that class when i call Sort function how do i reference which method to use ? Could you give me an example maybe ?

Comment: I've already said: if you want it to use an `IComparer`, you should pass that into the `Sort` method... it's as simple as that.